# Getting error DOM Level 3 Not implemented after removing xalan.jar

Tags: java, dom, soap, transform

There is a weird issue in my project like I'm getting the error in the webservice invoker

```
ERROR:  'DOM Level 3 Not implemented
```

When running with JAVA 1.6.0_45 on my local machine.After removing XALAN.jar from my project.
In one of the class i had replaced

```
import org.apache.xml.utils.QName;
```

With

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName; //its from jaxrpc.jar
```

The error appears while trying to apply the transform

```
TransformerFactory xf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            Document responseDocument = (Document) object.newDomNode(options);

            Transformer xformer = xf.newTransformer();
            xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            Result out = new StreamResult(writer);

            if (!xmlEscape) {
                ProcessingInstruction pi = responseDocument
                        .createProcessingInstruction(
                                Result.PI_DISABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "");
                responseDocument
                        .getDocumentElement()
                        .getParentNode()
                        .insertBefore(pi, responseDocument.getDocumentElement());
            }

            xformer.transform(new DOMSource(responseDocument), out);

            // remove the <![CDATA[ before returning the response
            return removeCdata(writer.getBuffer().toString());
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            throw new XMLSchemaException(
                    "Unable to generate request message due to " + e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new XMLSchemaException(
                    "Unable to generate request message due to " + e);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            throw new XMLSchemaException(
                    "Unable to generate request message due to " + e);
        }
```

The error happens in line

```
xformer.transform(new DOMSource(responseDocument), out);
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: the main reason of this error is that

```
TransformerFactory xf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

returns an instance of `weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory@16849e2a`

instead of

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

which comes as a default instance for transformerfactory in JAVA 6.

Answer (score 0):

Did a temproary patch to fix this issue by converting it to DOM3 compilant. while the actual solution is to stop using xecers,xbean.

```
Document responseDocument = (Document) object.newDomNode(options);
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc3 = builder.newDocument();
            Element newRoot = (Element) doc3.importNode(
                    responseDocument.getDocumentElement(), true);
            doc3.appendChild(newRoot);
```

and for the transform method passing the new doc3

```
xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc3), out);
```